# How to calculate average growth when it's negative?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

We have **annual** reports for company's revenue and can calculate annual growth as 
$yg = {y_{i+1} \over y_i}$.

And then we can calculate the average **monthly** growth as $mg = ({y_{i+1} \over y_i})^{1 \over 12}$.

So for reports `2000-12 $1m` and `2001-12 $2m` the average monthly growth would be `1.06`.

But how calculate monthly growth when the revenue became negative?

For reports `2000-12 revenue = $1m` and `2001-12 revenue = $-1m`?

P.S.

I need it for simple prediction. For example `2000-12 $1m` and `2001-12 $2m`  the revenue in `2002-02` could be predicted as $2 \times 1.06^2 = 2.25$

Comment: Why not the same formulas? You'll have ratios smaller than one (because $y_{i+1}<y_i$), and that should be fine.

Comment: Revenue is negative, earnings are negative, or revenue growth is negative?

Comment: @DougM the revenue became negative `2001 revenue = $1M, 2002 revenue = $-1M`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for negative growth rate: $y_0=100, y_1=80$

The growth rate from $t=0$ to $t=1$ is $g_{01}=\frac{80}{100}-1=0.8-1=-0.2$

So you can use the formula for growth rate no matter whether the growth rate is positive or negative:

$$g_{t,t+1}=\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_t}-1$$

Btw, the *growth factor* $1+g_{01}$ is still positive $1-0.2=0.8$

---

To apply the formula for the growth rate you need a meaningful zero point. That means that the values are *ratio scaled*. If $y_t$ is can  be negative as well, then a growth rate cannot be determined.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant - the revenue itself is negative (the net revenue could be negative even if the gross revenue is positive). So in this example it would be $y_0=100$ and $y_1=-80$

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin I´ve made an edit.

Comment: I see, thanks. I don't know how to find a proper zero point, maybe I'm not forming the question properly. May I ask you to take a look at this slightly different explanation of the issue? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470440/differential-equation-prediction-model-for-future-revenue

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin To the iproblem here: Maybe you should compare net revenues only or the gross revenues only.  It seems not a good idea to compare net and gross revenues. I´ve to admit that I´m not good in solving recurrence equations. But I´m pretty sure that someone else can help you.

Comment: Thanks anyway :). To be clear - I'm not comparing net to gross. I'm only talking about the net. But it can change the sign, could be that one year it's positive and the next became negative.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Then it is indeed not  meaningful to calculate a growth rate.

Comment: Negative revenue or negative earnings?

Comment: @DougM Is the question addressed to me?

Comment: @callculus No, this is really a question for the OP, I suppose.

Comment: @DougM negative net revenue (or earnings or net income) - the case when last year net revenue was positive and this year it became negative.